# How to prevent the addition of dragged item in tree which drag accepting.?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

i have two tree one tree lets say TreeDrag is drag enabled and other is drop enabled lets say TreeDrop.. when i drag item from TreeDrag to TreeDrop,, i want to show feedback and everything else normal except the addition of dragged item in TreeDrop....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `event.preventDefault()` while handling `DRAG_DROP` event:

```
private function tree_dragDropHandler(event:DragEvent):void
{
    event.preventDefault();

    tree.hideDropFeedback(event);
    DragManager.showFeedback(DragManager.NONE);
}
```

This handler should run before `Tree`'s own `DRAG_DROP` handler, this can be done via adding listener with priority:

```
tree.addEventListener(DragEvent.DRAG_DROP, tree_dragDropHandler, false, 1);
```